# Meteor app crashing only on FireFox

Tags: firefox, meteor

My Meteor app is crashing when run on FireFox with this error 4 times, the fourth one must be the one crashing it because this function is called about 30 times through out the html template.;

```
"Exception in template helper: @http://www.scr9.com:3000   /onepage.js?6b34dec0cc55de19e1c0ff682ac83dd9dce574d6:57:2
bindDataContext/<@http://www.scr9.com:3000/packages    /blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2727:14
Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions/<@http://www.scr9.com:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1606:14
Spacebars.call@http://www.scr9.com:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7f53771c84a2eafac2b561c9796dda0d8af8e7f5:171:12
Spacebars.mustacheImpl@http://www.scr9.com:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7f53771c84a2eafac2b561c9796dda0d8af8e7f5:108:10
Spacebars.mustache@http://www.scr9.com:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7f53771c84a2eafac2b561c9796dda0d8af8e7f5:112:16
Template.writeInvoice</</</<.value@http://www.scr9.com:3000/template.onepage.js?0b87a7326f8eda037de95427f14c078c4ab026ac:1005:18
Blaze._withCurrentView@http://www.scr9.com:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2043:12
.visitAttribute@http://www.scr9.com:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65"[…]
```

Works fine using Chrome, IE, and Safari. This is the function that it refers to at line 57;

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("formatMoney", function(str) {    
console.log(str);  // reports 0 in Chrome, IE, Safari. undefined in FF
if (typeof str == "string")
{
    str = Number(str); // line 57
}
str = str.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
if (str == "0.00")
{
    return "0.00";
} else {
    return "$"+str; 
}   
});
```

When it first starts I have no data yet so that function is just receiving str = 0. Any idea of what might be happening in FF?

Comment: Could you try getting more data by wrapping your code in an ugly try/catch and logging the exception? I remember it helping me when trying to debug odd Blaze behaviour on Firefox.

Comment: OK, I'll throw a few of those in and see if it reveals anything more.

Comment: Turns out this had nothing to do with the function itself. In `Tracker.autorun(function(){` farther down the page I subscribe to all the collections if the user is logged in and if they are not logged in I call a function to reset the session variables. That function was defined AFTER the first place that it was called from. That is what FireFox didn't like. It never subscribed to any data and therefore no values were ever defined,

Comment: If the question can't be properly answered, please delete it =)

Answer (score 1):

This can be because of 2 things:

First, regex, especially with a `/g` can cause bugs, without testing anything, I bet this is the problem.

Second, you've got a lot of coercion going on here, so first, I'd force the `str` argument to be a number before you pass it into the function. If this is coming from your DB this should be easy because you sanitized the data before it got in, right? *right?*

Implement both & your new function looks like this:

```
Template.registerHelper("formatMoney", function(str) { 
  var formatOpts = {style: "currency", currency: "USD"};
  return str ? str.toLocaleString("en-US", formatOpts ) : "0.00";
});
```

Comment: use I do sanitize the data. When I first started this I was often saving my numbers as strings that's why I had that in there. I'll try your solution once I can get back onto my server.

Comment: Finally got a new server up and running. I replaced the helper function with your code and now I get this error - spawn ENOMEM

Comment: If changing that helper function causes an `ENOMEM` then you're executing the helper function on the server and/or client, and that's no good...

Comment: I have it in myapp/myapp.js before `if (Meteor.isClient) {`. All server code is in a /server folder.

Comment: It gives a new error though - lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173 is where it crashed now. I suspect this is due to upgrading to all new packages when I installed it on the new server. I'll get that fixed and then try your code again :)

Comment: Stopped it from crashing with npm update --dev. Your code still throws ENOMEM and now my original code only works with that regex commented out.

Comment: Try the code in a meteorpad, ENOMEM is a node error & shouldn't have anything to do with client-side code...